# how tkinter switch page

Tags: python, class, user-interface, tkinter

I have a question about how tkinter switches page.
I've seen a lot of page switch examples using tkinter, but I cannot understand the structure and principle of how it works.
Especially, I cannot understand the initializing part and for loop at the class `tkinterApp()`, and `tk.Frame` class inheritance of each Page class.
Also, I have no idea `controller` and `parent` parameter means in `__init__` function.
Please give me some idea and source to study more. (I've already studied python class, but it's still confused)

THANK YOU!

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
  
 
LARGEFONT =("Verdana", 35)
  
class tkinterApp(tk.Tk):
     
    # __init__ function for class tkinterApp 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
         
        # __init__ function for class Tk
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
         
        # creating a container
        container = tk.Frame(self)  
        container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True) 
  
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
  
        # initializing frames to an empty array
        self.frames = {}  
  
        # iterating through a tuple consisting
        # of the different page layouts
        for F in (StartPage, Page1, Page2):
  
            frame = F(container, self)
  
            # initializing frame of that object from
            # startpage, page1, page2 respectively with 
            # for loop
            self.frames[F] = frame 
  
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky ="nsew")
  
        self.show_frame(StartPage)
  
    # to display the current frame passed as
    # parameter
    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
  
# first window frame startpage
  
class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller): 
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
         
        # label of frame Layout 2
        label = ttk.Label(self, text ="Startpage", font = LARGEFONT)
         
        # putting the grid in its place by using
        # grid
        label.grid(row = 0, column = 4, padx = 10, pady = 10) 
  
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text ="Page 1",
        command = lambda : controller.show_frame(Page1))
     
        # putting the button in its place by
        # using grid
        button1.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
  
        ## button to show frame 2 with text layout2
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text ="Page 2",
        command = lambda : controller.show_frame(Page2))
     
        # putting the button in its place by
        # using grid
        button2.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
  
          
  
  
# second window frame page1 
class Page1(tk.Frame):
     
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
         
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text ="Page 1", font = LARGEFONT)
        label.grid(row = 0, column = 4, padx = 10, pady = 10)
  
        # button to show frame 2 with text
        # layout2
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text ="StartPage",
                            command = lambda : controller.show_frame(StartPage))
     
        # putting the button in its place 
        # by using grid
        button1.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
  
        # button to show frame 2 with text
        # layout2
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text ="Page 2",
                            command = lambda : controller.show_frame(Page2))
     
        # putting the button in its place by 
        # using grid
        button2.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
  
  
  
  
# third window frame page2
class Page2(tk.Frame): 
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text ="Page 2", font = LARGEFONT)
        label.grid(row = 0, column = 4, padx = 10, pady = 10)
  
        # button to show frame 2 with text
        # layout2
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text ="Page 1",
                            command = lambda : controller.show_frame(Page1))
     
        # putting the button in its place by 
        # using grid
        button1.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
  
        # button to show frame 3 with text
        # layout3
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text ="Startpage",
                            command = lambda : controller.show_frame(StartPage))
     
        # putting the button in its place by
        # using grid
        button2.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
  
  
# Driver Code
app = tkinterApp()
app.mainloop()
```

this code is from geeksforgeeks.org (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tkinter-application-to-switch-between-different-page-frames/)

I've studied python class and so on. But I still cannot understand the structure and how it works. Especially Parameters and class inheritance.